# How to get this city from .txt and add this to database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

city.txt

```
City
City1
City2
City3
City4
City One
City Other
```

How to get this city from .txt and add this to database using PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty easy. You need to google to read file in PHP and write to database in PHP.

Here I'll start you off:

```
$file_handle = fopen("cit.txt", "rb");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
  $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
  // write your insert statement here, depending on your table structure.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or try:

```
$file = file_get_contents("city.txt");
$cities = explode("\n", $file);

foreach ($cities as $city) {

    $SQL = "INSERT INTO table_name (city) VALUES ('$city')";
    //now execute the SQL statement

}
```